# Get most recent posts from a blog built with Astro in a Single Page Application

Tags: single-page-application, astrojs

I have one single page application where I would like to show most recent posts from Astro blog. Does astro provide an API to easily access such information from another application?

Comment: You could add an [RSS feed](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/rss/) to your blog and request that from your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Astro Endpoints](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/#static-file-endpoints) to create custom API for my blog.

**src/pages/recent-posts.json.ts**

```
import { MarkdownInstance } from "astro";
import { Frontmatter, sortDateDescending } from "src/misc";

export async function get() {
    const allPosts = import.meta.glob<MarkdownInstance<Frontmatter>>("./posts/article/*.md", { eager: true }); // Vite
    const posts = sortDateDescending(Object.values(allPosts))
        .filter((ele) => ele.frontmatter.draft != true)
        .map((ele) => {

            return {
                title: ele.frontmatter.title,
                url: ele.url,
                thumbnailUrl: ele.frontmatter.image,
                content: ele.rawContent(),
                publishedDate: ele.frontmatter.date,
                tags: ele.frontmatter.tags,
            };
        });
    
    const LIMIT = 2;

    return {
        body: JSON.stringify(posts.slice(0, LIMIT)),
    };
}
```

Now, I can fetch the most recent posts from an endpoint `/recent-posts.json`.